# reduce CSS selectors with fewer lines

Tags: css

Is it possible to reduce these CSS classes??

```
body.bank #page_content input,
body.bank #page_content textarea,
body.bank #page_content .inp-checkbox,
.list-tr.bank input,
.list-tr.bank textarea,
.list-tr.bank .inp-checkbox,
body.creditor #page_content input,
body.creditor #page_content textarea,
body.creditor #page_content .inp-checkbox,
.list-tr.creditor input,
.list-tr.creditor textarea,
.list-tr.creditor .inp-checkbox,
body.debtor #page_content input,
body.debtor #page_content textarea,
body.debtor #page_content .inp-checkbox,
.list-tr.debtor input,
.list-tr.debtor textarea,
.list-tr.debtor .inp-checkbox{
    --opacity-border:35%;
}
```

Comment: Make one single reusable class?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`:where`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) or [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) pseudo-class.

```css
:where(.list-tr.bank, .list-tr.creditor, .list-tr.debtor) :where(input, textarea, .inp-checkbox),
:where(body.bank, body.creditor, body.debtor) #page_content :where(input, textarea, .inp-checkbox) {
    --opacity-border: 35%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to a usage I hadn't thought of before.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of `body.bank` why not simply `.bank` class? Same with `.list-tr`. And it seems like `#page_content` could be replaced with an HTML `main` element.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at has selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: This selector won't be helpful as the author tries to modify the opacity of inputs, while the `:has` selector will apply that to the parent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).